# homestead laravel vagrant not allowed windows

Tags: php, laravel-4, vagrant, homestead

Im trying to set homestead laravel vagrant on windows 7 and i get this error:

```
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse':
(<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 13
 column 9 (Psych::SyntaxError)
```

this is my yaml file:

```
authorize: C:/Users/Netanel/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - C:/Users/Netanel/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map:C:/projects 
      to: /home/vagrant/projects

sites:
    - map: test.com
      to: /home/vagrant/projects/test/public

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is lack of space after `map:`. You have:

```
folders:
    - map:C:/projects 
      to: /home/vagrant/projects
```

and it should be:

```
folders:
    - map: C:/projects 
      to: /home/vagrant/projects
```

Answer (score 1):

Marcin Nabiałek is right that it can be a problem with the Homestead.yaml.

In my case, using Sublime, File > Save with Encoding > UTF-8 solved the problem